# Is there a way to reference a function parameter that is shadowed by an inline class field?

Tags: scala

Is there a way to reference a shadowed parameter without resorting to naming the parameter `_name` or re-binding the parameter before the instantiation?

```scala
trait Stuff {
  def name: String
}
...
def create (name: String): Stuff = new Stuff {
  // this doesn't work since it references itself
  // how do I make the rhs refer to the parameter, 
  // not the method on the class?
  override def name = name
}
```

I would prefer to keep the name of the parameter the same, since callers will prob use named parameters. Re-binding would work, but that's a lot of repetition if there are a lot parameters.

Comment: `without resorting to naming the parameter _name or re-binding the parameter before the instantiation` Why such requirements? What is the actual goal here? This is how local variable shadow works for most languages.

Comment: @texasbruce Mainly because of the amount of repetition required if the method takes several parameters that are used as fields. We have a way to distinguish between inner class fields and outer class fields using self-types or using qualified names to deal with accidental shadowing in other situations. It just seems there should be a similar solution for method parameters... but maybe not.

Comment: I don't understand how more repetitive it would be to use a `_name` method parameter name

Comment: @GaëlJ  The OP wants to use named parameters so doesn't want a spurious `_` in the name

Comment: Sure, but the argument of why he doesn't want this is _"because of the amount of repetition required"_ which is somehow unclear to me

Comment: AFAIK the answer is just _"No, there is no way"_. That is all we can do, I understand your frustration with that; but you should move that requirement to the contributors **discourse** or to the bug tracker in **github**.

Comment: @GaëlJ The "repetition" concern is only in regards to re-binding inside the method. Using `_`-prefixed parameter names is only a problem in that it forces an implementation detail onto callers using named-parameters.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I would certainly accept that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct solution to the question, but this is perhaps a more typical pattern for creating objects in Scala:

```
class NamedStuff(name: String) extends Stuff

def create(name: String): Stuff = new NamedStuff(name)
```

Note that the `name` parameter to `NamedStuff` automatically overrides the `name` method in `Stuff`.